# How to mask an imported image as a plane in Blender 2.8?

Tags: masking, id-mask

I have the following scene in Blender 2.8:

[image]

I imported the Blender logo as a plane (File > Import > Images as Planes ---which is a plugin---).

I want to create a rectangular mask on the Blender logo to hide part of it, so I do the following:

[image]

To apply the mask to the image, I UV unwrap it first:

[image]

and then I go to the shader editor to apply a mask node to the plane containing the logo. But I cannot find such a node!:

[image]

If I render, I get the logo without the mask:

[image]

How can I apply the mask to the image?